# Не получается запустить цикл while с начала

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, while

Изучаю цикл `while` и делаю следующую задачу.

У меня есть некоторое количество конфет, которое я потихоньку ем и сообщаю об этом на экран.
Как только конфеты закончились, я спрашиваю себя: "Купить еще конфет?".
Если еще хочется сладенького, я еще покупаю какое-то количество конфет, если ввожу **`0`**, значит я сыт и выхожу из цикла.

Не получается вернуться в начало цикла:

```
x_bullets = 11
end_bullets = 1 

while x_bullets > end_bullets:
    x_bullets -= 1
    print(x_bullets)

    if x_bullets == end_bullets:
        print("Recharge")
        ammo_recharge = int(input())

        if ammo_recharge >= 1:
          continue
        else:
          print("You are out of ammo!")
          break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант

```
x_bullets = 11
end_bullets = 0 

while x_bullets:
    x_bullets -= 1
    end_bullets += 1
    print(f'Вы съели {end_bullets} конфету')
    if not x_bullets:
        ammo_recharge = int(input("\nКупить еще конфет? "))
        x_bullets += ammo_recharge

print("\nУ вас закончились конфеты!")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "за**у**ончились "?

Comment: @чистов_n спасибо

Comment: А у вас на скрине всё ещё "зауончились".

Answer (score 0):

```
if ammo_recharge >= 1:
     x_bullets = 11 # или значение ammo_recharge ?
```

а `break` в `else` не нужен

Кроме того, более естественно будет устанавливать `x_bullets` в 10, а `x_bullets -= 1` выполнять после использования (вывода) текущего значения

Comment: А ларчик оказывается просто открывался. Спасибо)